# Flutter failed to web scrapping getting data null or empty

Tags: flutter, web-scraping

on print(document) its => #document
on print(element) its => #null

Future scrapeWebsite() async {
try {
final response =
await http.get(Uri.parse('https://topping.truemoveh.com/'));
final document = parser.parse(response.body);
print(document);

```
  final element = document
      .getElementById('#package-card-tag--bestseller-prepaid-package-0');

  print(element);

  final text = element?.text ?? 'Element not found';

  setState(() {
    scrapedText = text;
  });
} catch (e) {
  print('Error: $e');
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for asking a question! I think users will have trouble understanding what your question is. Right now, it looks like an answer and not a question.